# My app icon is not visible in share menu windows 10 - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Icon is not being displayed in Share menu next to my app name. But its displayed correctly in icon
[image: Share menu Screenshot]

[image: App list]

I have added icons to all the options in visual studio

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

The assets you are using are right. At first, I didn't see any problem when I used RTM OS version (Version 1511, OS Build 10586.494). However, from your screenshot, it seems you are using Insider Preview Build. So I tested it again on Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 14393 and I can reproduce your issue.

Actually, your app icon is **not invisible**. It seems that System has cached the app icon used in Share menu when your app is deployed for the first time. After this, even we reset the app icon and redeploy the app, the icon in Share menu still won't change. I guess you've run your app with the default assets before you set your own assets. So in Share menu, it still use the default icon, but in Start panel, it is correct. You can created a new project with your own assets and then run this new project, you icon should be able to display in Share menu correctly.

This issue seems only affect Insider Preview Build. For Insider Preview issues, please feel free to share feedbacks with Microsoft. You can report this issue with Windows Feedback app. Your feedback has made Windows better!

Comment: Thanks for checking. I will report it.

Comment: @SanthoshManikandan I forgot to say your app icon is not  invisible in Share menu. It used the default icon instead. It seems that System cached the app icon when the app is deployed for the first time. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: OK Jay. Will look into it.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Is this fixed in the official Anniversary Update build? Using the current (fast) Insider Preview build, I experienced this problem with toasts, too!

Answer (score 0):

All Logos Related to UWP are stored in Package.appxmanifest. Edit it using an xml editor. See if there is any image that is still a default icon.

[image]

Comment: I did and none are set as default. I have uploaded the screenshot https://1drv.ms/f/s!AjJitK123ehCtGyF-oVTYnP0kbZU